# How to prevent stack overflow when using array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, memory, stack-overflow

I'm writing a program in C++ that calls a function in each iteration of a for-loop and stores the "results" in a .csv file. The function takes in 18 parameters and stores the results in an array. When I run the program with 10,000 iterations it works fine.
However, when I increase the iteration number to 100,000, it shows the stack overflow error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6E76D8408 in ConsoleApplication.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000ABB1693000)

The name of the function is wes5.cpp which is a void function. It stores the calculated results in the "results" array.
Note that some of the inputs of the function are randomly generated using for- loop. Can anyone tell me why it works fine with 10000 iterations and does not work with 100,000?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "wes.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int num_E = 100000;  // number of iteration

    double E1_max = 2000.0 * 1000; double E1_min = 300.0 * 1000;
    double E2_max = 100.0 * 1000; double E2_min = 1.0 * 1000;
    double E3_max = 100.0 * 1000; double E3_min = 1.0 * 1000;

    int num_H = 100.0;
    double H1_max = 12; double H1_min = 3;
    double H2_max = 25; double H2_min = 17;

    int num_L6000 = 100000; 
    double L6000_max = 7000; double L6000_min = 5000;
    
    //matrix declration for E
    double E1[num_E]; double E2[num_E]; double E3[num_E];
    double E4[num_E];double E5[num_E];
    
    //matrix declration for H
    double H1[num_E]; double H2[num_E]; double H3[num_E];
    double H4[num_E];double H5[num_E];

    //matrix declration for q
    double q[num_E]; 

    // variable description
    double u1 = 0.35; double u2 = 0.45; double u3 = 0.45; double u4 = 0.45; double u5 = 0.45;
    double la1 = 1; double la2 = 1; double la3 = 1;
    int l = 1;
    double p[] = { 0 };
    double a[] = { 5.9 };
    double xc[] = { 0 };
    double yc[] = { 0 };
    int l1 = 1;
    int ls = 1;
    double xs[] = { 0 };
    double ys[9] = {};
    double zs[] = { 0 };
    double results[900];
    //double my_results[10]; //num_E
    double X[9] = { 0, 8, 12, 18, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72 };

    for (int i = 0; i < num_E; i++)     //  Random data generation for E
    {
        int num_items_E1 = E1_max - E1_min + 1;
        int num_items_E2 = E2_max - E2_min + 1;
        int num_items_E3 = E3_max - E3_min + 1;

        E1[i] = E1_min + rand() % num_items_E1;
        E2[i] = E2_min + rand() % num_items_E2;
        E3[i] = E3_min + rand() % num_items_E3;
        E4[i] = E3[i];
        E5[i] = E3[i];
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < num_E; i++)     // Random data generation for H
    {
        int num_items_H1 = H1_max - H1_min + 1;
        int num_items_H2 = H2_max - H2_min + 1;

        H1[i] = H1_min + rand() % num_items_H1;
        H2[i] = H2_min + rand() % num_items_H2;
        H3[i] = 999;
        H4[i] = 999;
        H5[i] = 999;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < num_E; i++)     // Random data generation for q
    {
        int num_items_load = L6000_max - L6000_min + 1;
        double load = L6000_min + rand() % num_items_load;
        q[i] = load / (3.141652 * pow(a[0], 2));
    }

    std::fstream my_file;
    my_file.open("Output.csv");
    my_file << "E1" << "," << "E2" << "," << "E3" << "," <<
        "H1" << "," << "H2" << "," << "H3" << "," <<
        "q" << "," << "D0" << "," << "D1" << "," << "D2" << "," << "D3" << "," << "D4" << "," <<
        "D5"<< "," << "D6" << "," << "D7" << "," << "D8" << "\n";

    // running the main program
    for (int i = 0; i < num_E; i++) {

        double e1 = E1[i]; double e2 = E2[i]; double e3 = E3[i]; double e4 = E4[i]; double e5 = E5[i];
        double h1 = H1[i]; double h2 = H2[i]; double h3 = H3[i]; double h4 = H4[i]; double h5 = H5[i];
        p[0] = q[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

            ys[0] = X[j];

            wes5(&e1, &e2, &e3, &e4, &e5,
                &h1, &h2, &h3, &h4, &u1, &u2, &u3, &u4, &u5,
                &la1, &la2, &la3, &l,
                p, a, xc, yc,
                &l1, &ls, xs, ys, zs,
                results);

            //my_results[i] = results[700];

            if (j == 0) {
                my_file << E1[i] << "," << E2[i] << "," << E3[i] << "," <<
                    H1[i] << "," << H2[i] << "," << H3[i] << "," <<
                    p[0] << "," << results[700] << ",";
            }
            else {
                my_file << results[700] << ",";
            }


        }

        my_file << "\n";
    
    }
    my_file.close();
    
}
```

Comment: Please distill this down to a [mre]

Comment: You have 10 arrays which are each 100,000 elements each. This will overflow the stack.

Comment: While you're reducing the code to a [mcve], you can also edit your title so that it contains something descriptive instead of just redundantly repeating the tag information. The title should be clear enough about the problem or question that it will be of use to future readers here who are scanning a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title contains nothing that isn't available by reading the tags.

Comment: Try prefixing the declarations with the keyword: `static`.  This will place the variables into the same region as global variables, which usually has a bigger capacity than local variable storage.  If this doesn't work, use `std::vector`, or dynamically allocate the arrays.

Comment: This really worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your error, you are using Visual Studio, which has a default stack size of 1MB. In your code, you allocate 10 arrays of 100,000 doubles. Each of these arrays, therefore, is 800,000 bytes (double is 8-byte). Multiply that by 10, and you are up to 8MB of stack size for just your arrays. This is why you are getting a stack overflow error.

With size 10,000 you use 0.8MB of stack for your arrays, which is small enough to be able to still work.

You can use the [`/F`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=vs-2019) option to change the stack size, but I'd recommend rethinking your code instead. Perhaps a `vector` would be better?

Comment: Prefixing the array declarations with `static` will place the variables in the same space as global variables, which has more memory space than the stack.